# Update user profile throws PropertyNotEditableException in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

I am trying to update a sharepoint 2010 users profile and I keep getting this error:

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyNotEditableException: Property Not
Editable: This property can only be modified by an administrator. 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileValueCollection.
CheckUpdatePermissions()
```

I'm updating AD first with a separate block of code (which works). We are using the profile sync service so the value does eventually propagate down but we'd like to update the SP profile at the same time to show the change immediately.

code:

```
using (System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
  {
    Response.Write(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
    using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
    {
        try
        {
            SPServiceContext sc = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            UserProfileManager userProfileMangager = new UserProfileManager(sc);
            SPUser user = site.RootWeb.EnsureUser(loginName);
            UserProfile profile = userProfileMangager.GetUserProfile(loginName);
                try
                {
                    profile["WorkEmail"].Value = tbEmail.Text;
                    profile["WorkPhone"].Value = tbPhone.Text;
                    profile["company"].Value = tbCompany.Text;
                    profile.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblMesssage.Text = ex.ToString() + "<br/>";
                    lblMesssage.Visible = true;
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMesssage.Text = ex.ToString();
            lblMesssage.Visible = true;
        }
  }
});
panComplete.Visible = true;
panForm.Visible = false;
waiting.Visible = false;
litSuccess.Visible = true;
}
```

couple of those things are in there as I've searched around and tried different things. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we are doing at this point is writing to the hidden SP user profile list to spoof it until the AD sync takes place. This is not really the best answer but it's the only one I found so far. I'll happily accept a better answer if one comes.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
                     {
                         using (var site = new SPSite(CurrentWeb.Site.Url))
                         {
                             using (var web = site.OpenWeb(CurrentWeb.ID))
                             {
                                 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                 SPList userInfo = web.Site.RootWeb.Lists["User Information List"];
                                 SPListItem userItem = userInfo.Items.GetItemById(_SelectedUser.ID);
                                 userItem["Work phone"] = tbPhone.Text;
                                 userItem["Work e-mail"] = tbEmail.Text;
                                 userItem["company"] = tbCompany.Text;
                                 userItem.Update();
                             }
                         }
                     });
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem for this exception is not your code. It's a corrupt setting of the field which you want to change.
Look at the following [post](http://msscorner.de/en/2011/10/18/userprofile-manager-eigenschaft-kann-nicht-bearbeitet-werden-diese-eigenschaft-kann-nur-von-einem-administrator-geandert-werden/), because this one describe the solution and what you have to change on the field settings.

http://msscorner.de/en/2011/10/18/userprofile-manager-eigenschaft-kann-nicht-bearbeitet-werden-diese-eigenschaft-kann-nur-von-einem-administrator-geandert-werden/

I hope it helps

Comment: thanks. I asked this 7 months ago and we've moved on from the problem. It seems like I did that but I can't recall.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever is still trying to figure this out I found a solution thanks to [this](http://www.willswebworks.com/blog/?p=44) blog.

In Short:

You have to run the Update elevated and you have to set the`HttpContext.Current` to null. My personal guess is that it's a bug in SharePoint which behaves wrong if a context is set.

Code snippet:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
{
    HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    try
    {
        SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(httpContext);
        HttpContext.Current = null; // Hack !!!
        UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
        //.. update your property which has "IsAdminEditable" set to true and "IsUserEditable" set to false
    }
    finally
    {
        //restore old context
        HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this working in the end? From my experience, impersonation doesn't work too well with user profile service. It has a tendency to use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` instead of `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`. Try setting HttpContext.Current to null and seeing what happens.

Remember also that the current identity must have Managed User Profiles privileges.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I tried setting the httpcontext to null. I've tried with and without the `impersonation`. I've verified that the account being used at that point is a farm admin (dev environment). What we are doing at this point is writing to the hidden SP user profile list and spoofing it until the AD sync takes place :P

Answer (score 0):

Perform the below steps these will resolve the issue:

1) Restart **Sharepoint Administration** service and **Sharepoint timer** service from services.msc
2) stop and start user profile service using powershell
3) perform **IISRESET** on all web front servers and in app server as well
4) now clean your browser cache and access the url.